# Change element based on a option from select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this very simple table. I'm trying to hide rows based on the value of the column HIST.

Basically:

- If select says No, only show rows where HIST = false
- If select says Yes,  show all rows (doesn't matter if false or true)

I got stuck here but I'm not very far. Any help?

```js
$('#historySelect').change(function() {
  var option = $(this).val();
  if (option === "No") {

  } else {

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Show History
    <select id="historySelect">
        <option value="Yes">No</option>
        <option value="No">Yes</option>
    </select>
</label>

<table class="table dataTable no-footer" id="dataTable" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="grid" aria-describedby="dataTable_info" style="width: 100%;">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th class="text-center text-primary sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Name: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 66px;">Name</th>
      <th class="text-center text-primary hidden sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Historic: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 0px;">Historic</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="text-center hover-table odd" role="row">

      <td>Name</td>
      <td class="hist hidden">true</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-center hover-table odd" role="row">
      <td>Name</td>
      <td class="hist hidden">false</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly note that you have the value and text of the `option` elements swapped.

To achieve what you require you can use `has()` in conjunction with the `:contains` selector to get the `tr` elements that have a `.hist` element that contains `false`. Then you can `show()` or `hide()` as needed, like this:

```js
$('#historySelect').change(function() {
  var $rows = $('#dataTable tbody tr');
  if ($(this).val() === "No") {
    $rows.hide().has('.hist:contains(false)').show();
  } else {
    $rows.show();
  }
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Show History
  <select id="historySelect">
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
  </select>
</label>

<table class="table dataTable no-footer" id="dataTable" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="grid" aria-describedby="dataTable_info" style="width: 100%;">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th class="text-center text-primary sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Name: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 66px;">Name</th>
      <th class="text-center text-primary hidden sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Historic: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 0px;">Historic</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="text-center hover-table odd" role="row">
      <td>Name</td>
      <td class="hist hidden">true</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-center hover-table odd" role="row">
      <td>Name</td>
      <td class="hist hidden">false</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what does the `$rows` mean? I never saw that. I usually use `var rows`

Comment: The `$` prefix is a naming convention to show that the variable holds a jQuery object.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: Now I realised that you changed `$rows.hide().filter(':contains(false)').show();` it works either way

Comment: I changed it a this is more specific. The previous version would have hidden the row if *any* `td` contained `false`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector (it is case-sensative.).

```js
$('#historySelect').change(function() {
  var option = $(this).val();
  if (option === "No") {
    $(".hist:contains('false')").parent().hide();
    $(".hist:contains('true')").parent().show();
    
  } else {
    $(".hist:contains('true')").parent().hide();
    $(".hist:contains('false')").parent().show();
    
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Show History
    <select id="historySelect">
        <option value="Yes">No</option>
        <option value="No">Yes</option>
    </select>
</label>

<table class="table dataTable no-footer" id="dataTable" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="grid" aria-describedby="dataTable_info" style="width: 100%;">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th class="text-center text-primary sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Name: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 66px;">Name</th>
      <th class="text-center text-primary hidden sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Historic: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 0px;">Historic</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="text-center hover-table odd" role="row">
      <td>Name</td>
      <td class="hist hidden">true</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-center hover-table odd" role="row">
      <td>Name</td>
      <td class="hist hidden">false</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```